# How to save edited content in a file correctly using FileField?

Tags: django

I try to display content of text(.txt) file in `textarea` and save it if is edited.

How to save edited file correctly?

models:

```
class FileDb(models.Model):
    source = models.FileField(upload_to="source")
```

views:

```
def single_file(request,id):
    file = FileDb.objects.get(id=id)
    filename = file.source.read()
    #save edited file:
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST['content']
        file.source = content
        file.save()


    return render_to_response('single_file.html',{'file':file,'filename':filename},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

templates:

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="content">{{filename}}</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes">
</form>
```

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is. Does this code work? Are you getting an error? Or does it run but just not save?

Comment: @Sauce It just does not save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just don't assing a `string` to a `FileField`

```
file.source = content
```

you have to write the content to the file like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        from django.core.files import File
        f = open(file.source.path, 'w')
        content = request.POST['content']
        f.write(content)
        f = File(f)
        file.source = f
        file.save()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. `file.source.write(content)` in this line I have: `File not open for writing`

Comment: Maybe the last 3 lines aren't necessary since you're just editing the content of the file